# Odds of winning in my club's annual raffle when having two tickets

Tags: probability

This problem should be simple to solve for you guys, but not for me.
My Gun Club holds an annual raffle. There are 15 prizes, you can only win one prize per ticket. I purchased 2 tickets and there were 3500 tickets sold. What are the odds of winning?
This is the most tickets they have ever printed. My argument is that they hurt the odds of winning by printing/selling too many tickets.

Comment: Keep in mind that the "odds of winning" is not the only issue, expected winnings matters two.  Thus, if the odds go down but the prizes go way up, the two lotteries might be equally attractive.

Comment: To take an extreme example:  which would you pay more to play, a game where you toss a fair coin and get a dollar if it comes up Heads or a game where you roll a fair die and get a thousand dollars if it comes up $6$?

Comment: Are we replacing the tickets after they are drawn to win a prize, or do we throw it out? In other words, are we drawing with or without replacement?

Comment: [1] Winning * at least* one prize  or what? [2] Odds or probability ? They are not the same [3] Please edit in whatever you have tried

Answer (score 1):

The probability of wining (at least one ticket) is

$$ 1-\mathbb P(X= 0)=1- \frac{\binom{2}{0}\binom{3500-2}{15}}{\binom{3500}{15}}=1- \frac{3485 \times 3484}{3500 \times 3499}  $$

with $X \sim \mathcal {HG} (N=3500, m=2, n=15)$. The probability when $N$ is unknown is

$$P(N)=1- \frac{(N-15)(N-16)}{N (N-1)}$$

This function is decreasing in $N$ as $P(N-1) < P(N)$, so is the odds of winning

$$\text{Odds}(N)=\frac{P(N)}{1-P(N)}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{P(N)}-1}$$

decreasing in $N$, and thus they hurt it by printing/selling too many tickets.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the actual numbers to see that for a fixed number of prizes, the more tickets sold the less likely each ticket is to win. That is true no matter how many tickets one person happens to buy, or whether or not tickets can get multiple prizes. The more tickets they sell the less each one is worth (from the odds point of view) and the more money the Gun Club nets after buying the prizes. If they print "too many" tickets sales may drop if the buyers may balk when they think of the value of each ticket.

In your particular problem, if there were $15$ prizes and just $15$ then every ticket would be a winner. With thousands of tickets there are still just $15$ winners. The odds that you have one of those goes down as the number of tickets grows.